# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str error appears во время парсинга xml файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь распарсить xml файл который получаю в локальной сети, но получаю следуйщую ошибку:

```
print(value2['@id'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Сам код выглядит так:

```
import requests
import xmltodict 

url = 'http://192.168.1.8:8060/query/apps'
text = requests.get(url).text
#content = """
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
#<apps>
#<app id="31012" type="menu" #version="2.0.53">Vudu Movie &amp; #TV Store</app>
#</apps>
#"""
text = text.split('\n')
text = text[1:]
text = ''.join(text)
data = xmltodict.parse(text)
data = dict(data)

for key1, value1 in data.items():
  for key2, value2 in value1.items():
    print(value2['@id'])
    print(value2['@type'])
    print(value2['#text'])
```

Буду благодарен за помощь! (Уже долго игрался с этим=( )

Comment: Проверьте тип данных переменной `value2()` при помощи `print(type(value2))`. Мне кажется, что у вас там список, а не словарь, о чем и сообщает ошибка. А, вообще, можете добавить пример входных данных для переменной `data`, чтобы магию не использовать

Comment: Здраствуйте, @Dmitry запрос `print(type(value2))`  выдает  `<class 'list'>` .

Comment: @Dmitry , на счет переменной `data` , то входные данные следуйщие:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apps>
<app id="31012" type="menu" #version="2.0.53">Vudu Movie &amp; #TV Store</app>
<app id="31012" type="menu" version="2.0.53">Vudu Movie & TV Store</app>
<app id="630164" type="menu" version="2.0.56">VUDU LGC Beta</app>
</apps>`

Comment: @Dmitry Вы были правы, у меня клас лист (тобишь список), а как это можно исправить подскажите , пожалуйста? Я очень начинающий пока-что в этом вопросе=)

Comment: Чтобы подсказать, надо понимать какая информация вам нужна. Список - есть итерируемый позиционный объект, к членам  которого можно обращаться по индексу. Например, `value2[0]` будет забирать первый член списка, `value2[1]` - второй и т.д.

Comment: @Dmitry запрос `print(value2[1])` выводит  `OrderedDict([('@id', '630164'), ('@type', 'menu'), ('@version', '2.0.56'), ('#text', 'VUDU LGC Beta')])`, отсюда нужна следуящая информация:
630164 VUDU LGC Beta
Тобишь такой вывод ИД и названия апликации

Comment: @Dmitry основная идея в том, что-бы выводить в столбики ифнформацию об апках на девайсе в формате: ID Name в столбец
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: `value2[1]['@id']`, `value2[1]['@type']`, `value2[1]['@version']` и т.д. То есть вы сначала обращаетесь к члену списка, а потом к ключу

Comment: я дал предварительный ответ, но если вы добавите в вопрос переменную `data` перед `for`, но после всех манипуляций я возможно дополню ответ доп проверками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После выяснения в комментариях структуры данных, получается что для вывода сущностей надо использовать следующий обход по данным

```py
for key1, value1 in data.items():
    for key2, value2 in value1.items():
        if isinstance(value2, list):
            for item in value2:
                print(item['@id'])
                print(item['@type'])
                print(item['#text'])
```

То есть переменная `value2` содержит список, в котором каждый член - упорядоченный словарь. Обратившись к члену списка, далее можно забирать значения по ключам

Comment: Бомба, это работает! Большое спасибо, два дня ломал голову=) Выручили!

Comment: @Roman На здоровье. Один момент, что если данные которые будут приходить по запросу поменяются все может упасть, надо писать проверки и тесты